# Formatting Date. How to format int values into date format?

Tags: java, constructor, date-format

I am able to format a **CURRENT DATE** date using the appropriate imported methods but formatting my own date (My birthday for instance) is another story.
It works when a return it with the tostring method because I formatted it manually. 
Anyway, my question is: Can I format my birthday using the imports ?

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Date2 {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    private Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    // create a short version date formatter
    private DateFormat shorFormatter = SimpleDateFormat
            .getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT);
    // create a long version of date format
    private DateFormat longFormattter = SimpleDateFormat
            .getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG);
    // create date time formatter, medium for day, long for time
    private DateFormat mediuFormattter = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, SimpleDateFormat.LONG);

    /************ Constructors ***************/

    public Date2() {
    }

    public Date2(int dd, int mm, int yyyy) {
        this.day = dd;
        this.month = mm;
        this.year = yyyy;

    }

    /************ Getters setters ************/

    public Date getToday() {
        return today;
    }

    public String getShorFormatter() {
        return shorFormatter.format(today);
    }

    public String getLongFormattter() {
        return longFormattter.format(today);
    }

    public String getMediuFormattter() {
        return mediuFormattter.format(today);
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String tosString() {
        return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
}

public class DateFormatTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date2 date2 = new Date2(23, 05, 1973);
        System.out.println(date2.getShorFormatter());
        System.out.println(date2.getLongFormattter());
        System.out.println(date2.getMediuFormattter());
        System.out.println(date2.tosString());
    }
}
```

Comment: is your birthday something spectacular? no, it is just another date, so you can use the same formatting.

Comment: Why have you defined the class Date2? The DateFormat interface and SimpleDateFormat class only works with java.util.Date instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `getXXXFormatter()` methods use only the `today` field, and the constructor `Date2(int, int, int)` never changes that field, they will always format today's date.

You might want to change that constructor like this :

```
public Date2(int dd, int mm, int yyyy) {
    this.day = dd;
    this.month = mm;
    this.year = yyyy;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(yyyy, mm - 1, dd);
    today = calendar.getTime();

}
```

And to keep things consistent, you should update the `today` field in the setters as well. But I would recommend making this class immutable.

At any rate, it looks like you're trying to make something that resembles joda time's [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: I tried to assign my own value (birthday) to variable -today- but had a bunch of confusing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just realise, my question doesnt make any sense because its just a birthDay. And no need to format it.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
    public String getBirthday() {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);
      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.MAY);
      cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,1973);
      //http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
      String birthdayString = df.format(cal.getTime());//05/23/1975
      return birthdayString;
    }
```

Comment: This code snipet looks strange to me but i'll take a closer look and try to implement it later. Thank you

Comment: the assertEquals in the last line is from the JUnit test framework; the important parts are the lines above.  I'll edit out the JUnit shortly.